# Why is my component not updating/re-rendering when fetching data from firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a photo gallery in Angular 15.2.0, and was previously testing using angular's InMemoryDBService. The user selects a set of filters to apply to their search, then my gallery service queries the db for photos that match those filters and returns an observable of them, which I subscribe to in my gallery component and set the components 'photos' property to that value. My template looks like this:

```
    <app-filter-select
  *ngIf="!filtersChosen && filterList.length !== 0"
  [filters]="filterList"
  (Submitted)="setGallery($event)"
></app-filter-select>
<div *ngIf="filtersChosen">
  <div class="center-screen" *ngIf="loading">
    <mat-spinner class="center-screen"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
  <mat-grid-list
    *ngIf="photos && photos.length > 0"
    class="gallery-container"
    gutterSize="1em"
    cols="3"
  >
    <mat-grid-tile
      class="photo-holder"
      *ngFor="let photo of photos"
      [colspan]="1"
      [rowspan]="1"
    >
      <a [routerLink]="['/photos', photo.id]">
        <app-gallerycard
          (loaded)="onLoad()"
          [hidden]=loading
          [photo]="photo"
          style="display: flex; justify-content: center"
        ></app-gallerycard>
      </a>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

The grid tiles have their [hidden] attribute bound to a loading property which returns false once all the photos have loaded.

This was working fine, but now I'm trying to migrate to firestore for production and everything has fallen apart. Now when I set the component's photos property in the `subscribe` callback, it doesn't render the `<mat-grid-list>` at all, and so the loading property never changes, the spinner never un-renders, and the photos never appear. However this only happens the first time I navigate to the gallery page - if I click on the 'gallery' nav button again or go to a different page and come back, it renders the photos. I didn't make any changes to the gallery component, just to the gallery service where I changed the `getPhotosWithFilterArray()` method to query firestore instead of the inMemoryDb.

Here is the code called when filters are chosen and submitted:

```
photos?: Photo[];
  setGallery(data: any) {
    this.filtersChosen = true;
    const filterNames: string[] = [];
    data.filters.forEach((f: Genre) => {
      filterNames.push(f.name.toUpperCase());
    });
    this.galleryService
      .getPhotosWithFilterArray(filterNames)
      .subscribe((photos) => {
        this.photos = photos;
      });
  }
```

and here is the work the gallery service is doing:

```
  getPhotosWithFilterArray(filters: Array<string>): Observable<Photo[]> {
    const photosRef = collection(this.firestore, 'photos');
    const filteredPhotos = query(photosRef, where('genre', 'in', filters));
    return collectionData(filteredPhotos).pipe(
      tap((p) => console.log(p as Photo[])),
      map((p) => p as Photo[]),
      catchError(this.handleError<Photo[]>('getPhotosWithFilterArray', []))
    );
  }
```

Some of the things I've tried:

I changed the `<mat-grid-list>` to an *ngIf="photosFetched", a property which I then set to true in the `.subscribe` callback

I implemented `ngDoCheck()` to set photosFetched to true when the value of `photos` changed

I implemented `ngOnChanges()` to set photosFetched to true on any change that would be caught by `OnChanges`

I have not yet tried using async pipes to render the observable data, but I want to avoid that if possible - other parts of the component rely on `photos` being an array and not an observable.

I think it is possible that I need to extract the `<app-filter-select>` component to a different page and use its `Submitted` output as inputs for the gallery component, but if that's the case then this shouldn't have worked when I was using the InMemoryDb, yet it did.

Again, this only happens the first time I set my filters, and it wasn't a problem before I migrated to a live database. `photos` is getting bound to a valid array and photosFetched is updating its value, but for some reason neither of those things is triggering a state change in the template. What am I doing wrong here??

## Update

I couldn't manage to make this work the way I wanted it to - I believe this may be a genuine bug in Angular's change detection - but if you're here reading this and desperate, I found a workaround. Basically, my galleryService now fetches the entire document collection from firestore, but rather than the functions returning observable streams, I just have a getPhotos() function that sets a private photos array. Before any images on my website try to load, they check to see if the gallery's photos array is initialized using `photosInitializedYet() { return this._photos.length !== 0 }`. Since querying firestore is async, I can await the response from getPhotos(), and the *ngFor elements will wait to render until the Photo objects with their filepaths exist.

Again, this isn't ideal since I have to basically make a static copy of the firestore database in my service worker, but it works for now.

Comment: Seems to me like the order of things might be an issue here, since previous version was responding fast and the new one doesn't. Would be useful to see when and where the methods are called.

Comment: @MishaMashina When the page loads, there's a group of checkboxes and a submit button (the `<app-filter-select>` component). the submit button emits a custom event, Submitted, which contains the values of the checkboxes. the parent component has its `setGallery()` method bound to Submitted. So the `photos` variable is undefined on initial render, then when the filters are submitted it runs `setGallery()` which in turn runs `getPhotosWithFilterArray()` method in the gallery service class, returning an observable which I subscribe to in `setGallery()` and use that to set the `photos` variable.